# I cannot import docx module in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

I found many questions on this site realized with this problem but none of them was helpful. I uninstalled docx and install the latest version of python-docx, but still getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bluetooth_control\Deutsch\ofline version>py Spliter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Spliter.py", line 2, in <module>
    import docx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
C:\Users\Admin>python
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docx
>>>
```

But when i try to import docx module i get no error. Sublimetext is also displaing this error? Why?

Comment: Is your `py --version` different from your `python --version`?

Comment: Yes. My py version is 3.7.5 and my python version is 3.8.2. Should they be the same version?

Comment: You've likely installed `python-docx` for one *but not the other*.

Comment: Yes, that has worked, but SublimText is displaying the same error, although I am errorfree when i use terminal. What should I do to prevent the error from SublimText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly likely that you have installed docx module only for py, not for python. Try this:

```
python -m pip install python-docx
py -m pip install python-docx
```